# what will be output of code using equals operator

Tags: equals

what will be output of code using equals operator 
   package Test;

> > Class a is created
> >         class A
> >         {
> >             int i;
> >             int j;
> >             A()
> >             {
> >                 i=1;
> >                 j=2;
> >             }
> >         }
> >     test 7 is a class

```
public class test7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
```

> > obj1 andobj2 are objects

```
        A obj1 =new A();*object created*
        A obj2 = new A();
        System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));

    }

}
```

Comment: package Test;

class A
{
 int i;
 int j;
 A()
 {
  i=1;
  j=2;
 }
}

public class test7 {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
  A obj1 =new A();
  A obj2 = new A();
  System.out.println(obj1.equals(obj2));
  

 }

}

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please have a look on how to post a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Also, make sure your code is formatted so it can easily be read by others. Adding more code in the comment line should also be avoided, rather use the edit function for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the `equals()` method is so that you can override the default behavior:

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/equals-hashcode-methods-java/
>
> **Shallow comparison:**
>
> The default implementation of equals method is defined in
>   Java.lang.Object class which simply checks if two Object references
>   (say x and y) refer to the same Object. i.e. It checks if x == y.
>   Since Object class has no data members that define its state, it is
>   also known as shallow comparison.
>
> **Deep Comparison:**
>
> Suppose a class provides its own implementation of equals() method in
>   order to compare the Objects of that class w.r.t state of the Objects.
>   That means data members (i.e. fields) of Objects are to be compared
>   with one another. Such Comparison based on data members is known as
>   deep comparison.

In your case:

- Since obj1 and obj2 are two different objects...
- ...And since you haven't overridden the "equals()" method...
- Then you'll get the default: equals() will return "false"

Try it and see - compile your code and run it :)

PS:

Please read this tutorial:

[MKYong.com: Java – How to override equals and hashCode](https://mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/)